# How to reload page using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have function `addFeaturesToScene` which make a new URL using ajax.

After the function ends I need to go to the new site automatically

Here is code:

```
function addFeatureToScene(featureNid, sceneNid)
  {
  alert(featureNid + " -> " + sceneNid);

     $.ajax({
    type       : 'GET',
    url        : '/copy-feature-and-add-it-to-scene/' + featureNid + '/' + sceneNid,
    dataType   : 'json',
    async      : false,
    success    : function(reply) {

            //Code to open a page with a new url?

 }
 });

 }
```

Comment: reload or redirect to new page ?

Comment: why use AJAX at all if you want to do a GET? Just send you request to the url then return a redirect

Comment: you need to reload some part of the page using ajax or "go to the new site automatically"??

Comment: It doesn't seem like you really understand what AJAX does, at least from this question.

Comment: location.href sets your page to a new url, location.reload refresh the current page

Comment: I need to go to the new site automatically. To this site: url        : '/copy-feature-and-add-it-to-scene/' + featureNid + '/' + sceneNid,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window.location`

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.org';
```

Comment: Not working... I need to go to the url: '/copy-feature-and-add-it-to-scene/' + featureNid + '/' + sceneNid,

Comment: Then `window.location.href = '/copy-feature-and-add-it-to-scene/' + featureNid + '/' + sceneNid;`

Comment: It does not have anything to do with the function.